# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un update de tabla en phpmyadmin desde codeigniter usando la librería de webix?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mvc, codeigniter, webix

Entiendo que la conexión se realiza desde database.php de Codeigniter, ahí tengo que establecer tanto username, password, db_name, etc.

Por otro lado, también tenemos la librería de Webix, donde ya vienen las vistas, controladores y modelos, de hecho tengo ya código.

Este es mi código de vista webix, el archivo se llama **calendar.php**

```
<?php

use App\Models\CitaModel;


?>

<html> <head>
    <title>calendarPHP</title>
    <!-- Webix Library -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('PIXXEL/public/webix/codebase/webix.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('PIXXEL/public/webix/codebase/webix.css'); ?>" type="text/css">

    <!-- Scheduler -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('PIXXEL/public/scheduler/codebase/scheduler.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('PIXXEL/public/scheduler/codebase/scheduler.css'); ?>" type="text/css"> </head> <body>
    <!-- Scheduler constructor -->
    <script>
        webix.ui({
            view: "scheduler",
            url: "https://docs.webix.com/calendar-backend/",
            on: {
                onItemClick: function(id) {
                // Obtener los datos del evento seleccionado
                var event = this.getEvent(id);
                var eventData = {
                    eventoprueba: event.text,
                    fecha: event.start_date,
                    hora_inicial: event.start_date.getHours() + ":" + event.start_date.getMinutes() + ":00",
                    hora_final: event.end_date.getHours() + ":" + event.end_date.getMinutes() + ":00",
                    notas: event.notes
                };

                // Enviar los datos al backend para guardarlos en la base de datos
                webix.ajax().post("http://localhost/PIXXEL/app/Controllers/CitasController/actualizar_cita", eventData);
                }
            }
            });
    </script> </body> </html>
```

por acá tengo el Modelo llamado **CitaModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class CitaModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'citas';

    public function insertCita($data)
    {
        return $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Y este es mi controlador llamado **CitasController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\CitaModel;

class CitasController extends BaseController
{
    public function insertar_cita()
    {
        $citaModel = new CitaModel();

        // Obtener los datos enviados por Webix
        $eventoprueba = $this->request->getPost('eventoprueba');
        $fecha = $this->request->getPost('fecha');
        $hora_inicial = $this->request->getPost('hora_inicial');
        $hora_final = $this->request->getPost('hora_final');
        $notas = $this->request->getPost('notas');

        // Crear un array con los datos de la cita
        $datosCita = [
            'eventoprueba' => $eventoprueba,
            'fecha' => $fecha,
            'hora_inicial' => $hora_inicial,
            'hora_final' => $hora_final,
            'notas' => $notas
        ];

        // Insertar la cita en la base de datos
        $citaModel->insertCita($datosCita);

        // Enviar una respuesta al cliente (Webix)
        return $this->response->setJSON(['success' => true]);
    }

    public function actualizar_cita()
{
    $citaModel = new CitaModel();

    // Obtener los datos enviados por Webix
    $eventoprueba = $this->request->getPost('eventoprueba');
    $fecha = $this->request->getPost('fecha');
    $hora_inicial = $this->request->getPost('hora_inicial');
    $hora_final = $this->request->getPost('hora_final');
    $notas = $this->request->getPost('notas');

    // Crear un array con los datos actualizados de la cita
    $datosCita = [
        'eventoprueba' => $eventoprueba,
        'fecha' => $fecha,
        'hora_inicial' => $hora_inicial,
        'hora_final' => $hora_final,
        'notas' => $notas
    ];

    // Actualizar la cita en la base de datos
    $citaModel->update($datosCita);

    // Enviar una respuesta al cliente (Webix)
    return $this->response->setJSON(['success' => true]);
}
```

Se supone que la función buena es la segunda, la de actualizar_cita, porque me di cuenta que tengo que hacer sentencias UPDATE en phpmyadmin para actualizar la tabla ya creada.

¿Qué es lo que no me hace sentido?

Entiendo que hacemos referencia el script scheduler.js de Webix, entiendo también que ese archivo no es modificable, vaya, se puede modificar pero el código es illegible, no hay espacios ni indentaciones, además en Internet dice que no hay necesidad de hacerlo, entiendo, claro que hay que referenciarlos () y tal.

Lo que no me hace sentido, es, cómo le digo al código que actualice mi tabla 'Citas' cuando le doy al botón **Done** de mi vista webix:

**Vista WEBIX**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta vista, claro, viene de calendar.php de la carpeta vistas...

Cómo párrafo final, quisiera que al yo darle clic en "Done" se actualice mi tabla de citas dependiendo de los datos que ingresé en mi form (?:ni siquiera sé si es un form) de scheduler.js, cómo puedo lograr eso?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he visto en la necesidad de también pedir ayuda a ChatGPT pero sabemos que para la lógica no es muy bueno, aún así me aclaró algunas ideas.

GRACIAS

Comment: tienes un concepto errado: phpmyadmin es un simple frontend para la base de datos que puede ser mysql o dbmaria, todo lo que hagas, en realidad lo haces sobre la base de datos el phpmyadmin, no tiene nada que ver, simplemente mostrar los cambios que hayas realizado en la base de datos ...

Comment: segundo a tu clase "CitaModel.php" le hace falta el metodo "update" no hace sentido por que te faltan cosas y no estas comprendiendo realmente como funciona .. el MVC y el OOP...

Comment: para recolver estos problemas tienes que hacer debug, si no sabes hacerlo te recomendaria estudiar: "¿como hacer debug en codeigniter?"

Comment: Entonces tengo que conectar con phpmyadmin con MySQL?, pero puedo hacer consultas en phpmyadmin, incluso cuando selecciono la tabla me hace el query SELECT * FROM tabla

2. Gracias, haré esa adición y sí, realmente me falta comprender cómo funciona todo

Comment: 3. gracias, buscaré lo del debug en codeigniter

Comment: no estas comprendiendo .... si yo te pregunto que es phpmyadmin que me responderias?

Comment: diría que es un administrador de bases de datos y usa el lenguaje mysql

Comment: ok y que hace un administrador de base de datos???

Comment: claro, administra bases de datos

Comment: ok te hago todas estas preguntas por que de salida veo que no estas familiarizad@ con los conceptos y funcionalidades... y tratare de explicarte por que:

Comment: **PHPmyadmin** no es un administrador de base de datos, es una herramienta que de conecta usando php al administrador de la base de datos (motor MySQL).

en pocas palabras phpmyadmin es como una interface grafica hecha en html+css+javascript+php para interactual con el administrador de la base de datos.

Comment: entonces da la casualidad que como herramienta el te permite generar algo que se llaman queroies; esos que se llaman insert, select, update y delete y muchos otros mas, pero que haga esto no quiere de decir que te vas a conectar al PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: no hay forma alguno que phpmyadmin forme parte de la estructura o conectividad de tu sistema. es simplemente una herramienta para ver y probar cosas de una forma facil

Comment: me dices si quedo claro el concepto de phpmyadmin

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147165/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-zaraterdz).